# href is blank then got the error even having a script cathch it

Tags: javascript, iis-7

I have javascript which return false if the href  is  blank; otherwise it return true. It worked when I run debug on VS2008. However when I put all my pages on IIS7. It has error 403_Forbidden: Access is denied. 
Let said my URL:$http://myapp.ca/Order/Order.aspx?Id=14063&OrderID=1255
After click the URL, the page goes $http://myapp.ca/Order/
Does anyone tell me how can I solve the issue. Thanks in advance.

There is my code:

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) 
        {
            anchors[i].onclick = function() 
            {
                var link = this.getAttribute("href");             
                if (link == '') {
                    return (false);
                }

                else {                    
                 return (true);
                }
            };

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that there was one bracket too many, this will do the trick:
(so compare to `null` instead of an empty string)

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++){
    anchors[i].onclick = function(){
        var link = this.getAttribute("href");             
        if (link === null) {
            return (false);
        }else {                    
            return (true);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: What error do you get exactly? This Fiddle works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/vWuh5/

Comment: @jsfiddle.net/vWuh5, I got 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.

Comment: You get a 403? that is in no way related to this script, error 403 is a server response. So that is a problem of a whole different origin. Maybe you are just trying to reach a page that you are not allowed to access? (seems the whole site that you are mentioning in your questioin is down)